# PHP SimpleXML Children Node Data Extract

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have been trying extract the node data's children using a foreach loop. I can get the main node data without problems, but the child data only gets the first data set then repeats. can someone maybe tell me what i am doing wrong? I got the example going from the offical documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php

This is my test xml

```
<Result>
<Result_Data>
    <Root_XML>
        <Stock>
            <Stock_Code>28</Stock_Code>
            <Barcode>28</Barcode>
            <Multiple_Barcodes>
                <Barcode>BARCODE1</Barcode>
                <Barcode>BARCODE2</Barcode>
            </Multiple_Barcodes>
            <Sell_Prices>
                <Sell_Price>
                    <Inclusive>10</Inclusive>
                    <Exclusive>8.77193</Exclusive>
                </Sell_Price>
                <Sell_Price>
                    <Inclusive>0</Inclusive>
                    <Exclusive>0</Exclusive>
                </Sell_Price>
                <Sell_Price>
                    <Inclusive>0</Inclusive>
                    <Exclusive>0</Exclusive>
                </Sell_Price>
            </Sell_Prices>
            <New_Prices>
                <New_Price>0</New_Price>
                <New_Price>0</New_Price>
                <New_Price>0</New_Price>
                <New_Price>0</New_Price>
            </New_Prices>
            <Work_In_Progress_Quantity>0</Work_In_Progress_Quantity>
            <Extended_Description />
            <Onhand>0</Onhand>
        </Stock>
        <Stock>
            <Stock_Code>123</Stock_Code>
            <Barcode>123</Barcode>
            <Multiple_Barcodes>
                <Barcode>BARCODE123</Barcode>
                <Barcode>BARCODE124</Barcode>
            </Multiple_Barcodes>
            <Sell_Prices>
                <Sell_Price>
                    <Inclusive>10</Inclusive>
                    <Exclusive>8.77193</Exclusive>
                </Sell_Price>
                <Sell_Price>
                    <Inclusive>0</Inclusive>
                    <Exclusive>0</Exclusive>
                </Sell_Price>
                <Sell_Price>
                    <Inclusive>0</Inclusive>
                    <Exclusive>0</Exclusive>
                </Sell_Price>
            </Sell_Prices>
            <New_Prices>
                <New_Price>0</New_Price>
                <New_Price>0</New_Price>
                <New_Price>0</New_Price>
                <New_Price>0</New_Price>
            </New_Prices>
            <Work_In_Progress_Quantity>0</Work_In_Progress_Quantity>
            <Extended_Description />
            <Onhand>0</Onhand>
        </Stock>            
    </Root_XML>
</Result_Data>
```

This is my php code

```
$file = file_get_contents('play.xml', true);  
$XMLtoSAVE = new SimpleXMLElement($file);
foreach ($XMLtoSAVE->Result_Data->Root_XML->Stock as $element) {
echo $element->Stock_Code . "\n";

    //Child Node Data - Barcode
    foreach ($XMLtoSAVE->Result_Data->Root_XML->Stock->Multiple_Barcodes as $element) {
    echo $element->Barcode . "\n";
    }


}
```

**This is the output:**

28

BARCODE1

123

BARCODE1

**Expected Output:**

28

BARCODE1

BARCODE2

123

BARCODE123

BARCODE124

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the inner loop use `foreach ($element->Multiple_Barcodes->Barcode as $barcode) { echo $barcode; }`.